# Two nested async tasks in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Let's say I have two async tasks A and B. If I execute task B in the doInBackground method of task A, will onPostExecute of task A occur after task B finishes?

Comment: that depends on how many executor threads you have, and how long task A and task B will take

Comment: you have tried it out, haven't you?

Comment: @panini what if task B takes longer than task A?

Comment: then B will finish after A

Comment: The order of finishes for asynctasks is should be unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one asyntask(or Loader) an parallel your work with FutureTasks. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html